# Please don't forget to accept an answer

Tags: discussion

If you think your questions has been answered entirely, please don't forget to mark an answer as accepted so people can focus on unsolved issues.

Comment: At first, I thought you meant to append `[solved]` to the title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Except, please *don't* add comments asking users to accept an answer. Accepting an answer is an optional activity, and the system already has processes in place to remind the user to accept an answer when it is appropriate.

While well meaning, constantly reminding users *"can you accept an answer...? You should accept an answer..."* starts to look somewhat harassing when they start to accumulate across the site.

Comment: You are right... Still don't get why people are downvoting the general idea (which is even edited now to leave out the controversial bit). If you think you're question was answered to your full satisfaction (or whatever) please click the checkmark.

Comment: Touché, you got me ;) Guess there is nothing more to so about this.